# Increase wordpress menu Depth

Tags: menus

i want to increase my nav menu depth as its only showing upto 3rd level. current is wp_nav code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main_menu', 'container_id' => 'navbar-collapse-1',
        'container_class'=>'navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right',
        'menu_class'=>'nav navbar-nav',
        'fallback_cb'=>false, 
        'items_wrap' => '%3$s', 
        'container'=>false,              
        'walker'=> new Bunch_Bootstrap_walker()  

    ) ); ?>
```

i also tried adding depth like below but nothing happened:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main_menu', 'container_id' => 'navbar-collapse-1',
        'container_class'=>'navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right',
        'menu_class'=>'nav navbar-nav',
        'fallback_cb'=>false, 
        'items_wrap' => '%3$s', 
        'container'=>false,
        'depth'=>'6',                
        'walker'=> new Bunch_Bootstrap_walker()  

    ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

depth must be an integer, try with this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
  'theme_location' => 'main_menu',
  'container_id'   => 'navbar-collapse-1',
  'container_class'=> 'navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right',
  'menu_class'     => 'nav navbar-nav',
  'fallback_cb'    => false,
  'items_wrap'     => '%3$s',
  'container'      => false,
  'depth'          => 6,
  'walker'         => new Bunch_Bootstrap_walker()
) ); ?>
```

from [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/):

**depth** *(int) How many levels of the hierarchy are to be included. 0 means all. Default 0.*